# Webservice returns EndPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I have a web service (LoginService) I am calling from another web service (AndroidService). I have a simple method for testing the connection and it isn't working.

In LoginService I have a method called getStuff(string password) - it returns a string in JSON. When I access it via browser directly, at http://localhost/LoginService/LoginService.svc/getStuff/foo it works as it should be. When I try the same via the other web service, it fails with the exception in subject and an InnerException "The server returned 404 Not Found".

Here is the LoginService definition:

```
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "getStuff/{password}")]
        string getStuff(string password);
```

Here is the code from AndroidService:

```
    public string getStuff(string password)
    {
        string endpoint_address = "http://localhost/LoginService/LoginService.svc/";

        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(endpoint_address);

        client = new LoginServiceClient(binding, address);
        return client.getStuff(password);
    }
```

And the AndroidService definition:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "getStuff/{password}")]
    string getStuff(string password);
```

Here is the full exception:

```
Request Error
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/LoginService/LoginService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at AndroidServiceSpace.LoginServiceReference.ILoginService.getStuff(String password) at AndroidServiceSpace.LoginServiceReference.LoginServiceClient.getStuff(String password) in C:\AndroidServiceUUS\trunk\services\AndroidService\AndroidService\Service References\LoginServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 264 at AndroidServiceSpace.AndroidService.getStuff(String password) in C:\AndroidServiceUUS\trunk\services\AndroidService\AndroidService\AndroidService.svc.cs:line 77 at SyncInvokegetStuff(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings >
      <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_UserService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <security mode="None" />
          </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>      
     <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/LoginService/LoginService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_UserService" contract="LoginServiceReference.ILoginService" />
  </client>      
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AndroidBehaviour" name="AndroidServiceSpace.AndroidService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="AndroidServiceSpace.IAndroidService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AndroidBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Moved LoginService to remove server to get Fiddler requests:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
4   502 HTTP    10.0.4.12:50271 /AndroidService.svc/getStuff/ggnore 512     text/html; charset=UTF-8    chrome:4132         
5   502 HTTP    10.0.4.12:50271 /favicon.ico    512     text/html; charset=UTF-8    chrome:4132         
6   400 HTTP    localhost:50271 /AndroidService.svc/getStuff/ggnore 4 565   private     text/html   chrome:4132         
7   404 HTTP    localhost:50271 /favicon.ico    2 310   private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:4132         
8   200 HTTP    Tunnel to   clients4.google.com:443 0           chrome:4132         
9   404 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc/$metadata    1 565   private     text/html; charset=UTF-8    vwdexpress:5772         
10  200 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc  2 790   private     text/html; charset=UTF-8    vwdexpress:5772         
11  200 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc/mex  10 195  private     application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 vwdexpress:5772         
12  404 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc  1 565   private     text/html; charset=UTF-8    vwdexpress:5772         
13  200 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc?disco    289 private     text/xml; charset=UTF-8 vwdexpress:5772         
14  200 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc?wsdl 3 902   private     text/xml; charset=UTF-8 vwdexpress:5772         
15  200 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc?xsd=xsd0 1 969   private     text/xml; charset=UTF-8 vwdexpress:5772         
16  200 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc?xsd=xsd2 1 521   private     text/xml; charset=UTF-8 vwdexpress:5772         
17  200 HTTP    maker.server    /LoginService/LoginService.svc?xsd=xsd1 2 273   private     text/xml; charset=UTF-8 vwdexpress:5772         
18  200 HTTP    localhost:50271 /   2 756       text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:4132         
19  404 HTTP    localhost:50271 /favicon.ico    2 310   private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:4132         
20  400 HTTP    localhost:50271 /AndroidService.svc/getStuff/ggnore 4 565   private     text/html   chrome:4132         
21  404 HTTP    localhost:50271 /favicon.ico    2 310   private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:4132
```

Comment: I guess you need to be using WebHttpBinding rather than BasicHttpBinding as your service seems to be REST and andriod accesses it using REST than SOAP

Comment: Changed it to WebHttpBinding and now I get InvalidOperationException, saying "Manual addressing is enabled on this factory, so all messages sent must be pre-addressed." =(

Comment: Have you tried to access the service from Fiddler and see waht is the response you get. also please do post your Service config file

Comment: Posted web.config, changed the code to be client = new LoginServiceClient(); instead of client = new LoginServiceClient(binding, address);

Comment: Can you post the raw request from fiddler? I see that your calling loginservice from andriodservice if i am not wrong. Is that correct?

Comment: There was no endpoint listening at http://maker.server/LoginService/LoginService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shown with a similar scenarios as yours:

LoginService:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "getStuff/{password}")]
string getStuff(string password);
```

AndroidService:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "getStuff/{password}")]
string getStuff(string password);
```

Now my LoginService implementation:

```
public string getStuff(string password)
{
    if ( password == "test")
          return "Success";
    else
          return "Failure";
}
```

Now my AndroidService implementation:

```
public string getStuff(string password)
{
    // NOTE: Below 2 lines to acccess the login service via SOAP 
    // assuming that you have added a service reference to your project and added the needed config entries in you androidservice config file
    LoginServiceClient client = new LoginServiceClient(binding, address);
    return client.getStuff(password);

     // NOTE: Below code to access it RESTfully 
     string responseMessage = null;
     var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/LoginService/LoginService.svc/getStuff/" + password) as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null)
    {
        request.ContentType = "application/json";      
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                        responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();                        
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                }
    }
    if (responseMessage == "Success")
    {
        return "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Failure";
    }
}
```

Now from Fiddler i perform the below request (shown in Raw)

```
GET http://localhost:50271/AndroidService.svc/getStuff/ggnore HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
```

Web.config as shown :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings >
      <webHttpBinding>
          <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <security mode="None" />
          </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
        <endpoint address="http://maker.server/LoginService/LoginService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginService"
    contract="ILoginService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginService" />
  </client>             
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AndroidBehaviour" name="AndroidServiceSpace.AndroidService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="AndroidServiceSpace.IAndroidService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AndroidBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

NOTE: I am assuming that your LoginService is hosted as a seperate RESTful service and hence accessing it using the WebRequestClass. If the LoginService is in the same project then define a service element for the LoginService similar to AndroidService and that should be enough.

Comment: Well yes I could get it to work by making the http requests manually, but that would make the whole implementation kind of vague, having to define requested url for every implementation. -- I want to be able to do LoginServiceClient client = new LoginServiceClient(); and then use the methods via client.getStuff("string");

Comment: The process of using LoginServiceClient client = new LoginServiceClient(); refers to using SOAP based web service and that is possible as well by just adding a service reference of the LoginService in AndroidService and using the above code rather than using a WebRequest class to perform a call to it.

Comment: I have added service reference of loginservice to androidservice. When I type LoginServiceClient client = new LoginServiceClient(); and then client. it suggests the method getStuff there, so I know it can see the exposed webservice. It just doesn't work and I am utterly clueless on how to get it to work.

Comment: Can you post the server config for LoginService? Also see my updated web.config on androidService that would have a client element referring to LoginService endpoint and its associated BasicHttpBinding element (assuming that login service is exposed using basicHttpbinding without any security)

Comment: Marked your answer as correct since it would have effectifely given the right result for using loginservice as rest. I started a new project, copypasted everything in it and now it works. :S